# Design for a template class

Tags: java, design, object-oriented

I have an abstract class `abstract class MathFunc` that is used to implement the mathematical functions Rastrigin, Griewangk and Rosenbrock in their specific classes `final class Rastrigin extends MathFunc`,  `final class Griewangk extends MathFunc` and `final class Rosenbrock extends MatjFunc`.

This hierarchy of classes and how they are defined so far works flawlessly so I think there is no need to look for improvements on this area.

Now I have to implement another class `Generation` that will have some `ArrayLists` in it but the thing is I need to have a Generation implementation for each mathematical function described above.

So that I need something like:

```
ArrayList<Rastrigin> rast = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Griewangk> grie = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Rosenbrock> rose = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside these lists I have some Rastrigin/Griewangk/Rosenbrock objects that I need to instantiate.

I know from the past projects in C++ that I can use templates to specify a generic data type and I'm thinking that this is my solution. My implementation so far looks like this:

```
public class Generation <MathFunc> {
    private final ArrayList<MathFunc> pop = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<MathFunc> nextpop = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<MathFunc> Crossover = new ArrayList<>();

    Generation(MathFunc tp)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < PopSize; i++)
        {
            pop.add(tp);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is: can I use the abstract class to instantiate the objects that rely on it? Is there another way to do it? I'm quite confused about the usage of templates.

But doing `Generation(Mathfunc tp)` seems a little weird to me since abstract classes are not instantiable.

Comment: You may want to adjust your question, as you're not as much asking for the design of a template class as you seeking aid on using its derivations generically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515026/how-to-instantiate-t-type-inside-a-template-class). It looks like factory pattern would work best in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To answer a bit of what you are asking: you can use the abstract as the declaring type, the type of your reference, but the (real) object should be that of a concrete/implementing type. Probably you already got that; indeed, in this case, probably using interfaces would be a plus.

To help some more, a nice tutorial on the template method is here: http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html. Also, please read a bit about Java generics usage: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instantiate the `Mathfun`c class.  Instead, what you can do is to instantiate one of `MathFunc`'s sub classes and treat the object as an instance of `Mathfun`.  For example:

```
MathFunc math = new Rastrigin();
Generation g = new Generation(math);
```

Comment: Well I guess that abstract classes are not instantiable. If it were an interface it would work I guess.

Comment: @Edeph - Interfaces are not instantiable either.